# Why is the set $S = \{ (x,y,z) \in \mathbb{N}^3 : x^2 + 4yz = p, p \text{ prime} \}$, finite

Tags: number-theory

I am looking at this proof: http://people.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/zagier/files/doi/10.2307/2323918/fulltext.pdf

We are given that this set is finite. But it is not immediately obvious to me why.  The rest of the proof makes sense, so I want to understand this part.  Can someone help?

Comment: $x$ is at most $\sqrt{p}$ and $y, z$ are at most $\frac{p}{4}$.

Comment: The "$p$ prime" clause does not belong in the definition of $S$, since it suggests taking a union over all primes $p$ rather than one specific $p$.

Comment: $$S=\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{N}^3:x^2+4yz=p,\text{any prime }p\}$$ and $$S=\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{N}^3:x^2+4yz=p\},\text{some prime }p$$ mean two different things.

Answer (score 2):

Note that $x \in \{0,1,2,\ldots,\sqrt{p}\}$, $y \in \left\{1,2,\ldots,\dfrac{p-x^2}4 \right\}$ and $z \in \left\{1,2,\ldots,\dfrac{p-x^2}{4y}\right\}$. Hence, clearly we have
$$\# S \leq \sqrt{p} \times \left(\dfrac{p}4 \right)^2 = \dfrac{p^{5/2}}{16}$$